# What is a node in C?

Tags: c, nodes, cs50

I'm working on cs50 pset5 speller, and in the lecture they introduce a new thing called nodes. What is a node? I didn't really understand what they said in the video. When I tried googling it, I got some sites that explained what a node is, but I didn't really understand. I'm new to c so I'm not accustomed to what I call 'coding words'. For instance, I found this on a site about nodes: **A dynamic array can be extended by doubling the size  but  there  is  overhead  associated  with  the  operation  of  copying  old  data  and  freeing the memory associated with the old data structure.** What is that supposed to mean? Please help me figure out what a node is because they seem important and useful, especially for pset5.
My node is defined like this:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;
```

Here is the link to the walk-through of speller pset5: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/5/speller/

Comment: What do you mean? And also I only started learning c because it's in the course. I wasn't planning to learn it before. I want to continue on with the course and take the track about Web programming.

Comment: In any case, wild guess: `node` is some kind of structure defined in CS50 for you to use (a ptset node in this case I guess). And of course, the author(s) did not make it clear enough that this has nothing to do with standard C types.

Comment: My guess is a `node` referring to linked list ,tree, or graph.

Comment: and all of this has nothing to do with C, or any specific programming language, for that matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node is a common terminology that is used to demonstrate a single block of `linked list` or `tree` or related data structures.

It is a convention to name it node, otherwise you can call it with any name.

### Standard

C++

```cpp
struct node{
int data;
int *next;
};
```

or in Python

```py
class Node:
   def __init__(self, data, next= None):
       self.data = data
       self.next = next
```

But you can call it with anyname

### Not Standard

C++

```cpp
struct my_own_name{
int data;
int *nextptr;
};
```

or in python

```py
class my_own_name:
    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
```

Answer (score 6):

A "node" is a concept from graph theory. A graph consists of nodes (vertices) and edges that connect the nodes.

A node in C can be represented as a *structure* (a `struct`) that has all the necessary data elements "on board" to implement a graph. Optionally a structure may be required that represents the edges.

Example:

```
typedef struct NODE {
    int node_id;
    struct EDGE *edgelist;
} tNode;

typedef struct EDGE {
    tNode *from, *to;
    struct EDGE *next;
} tEdge;
```

Note: the term "node" may also be used in other contexts, for example the nodes of a binary tree, the nodes of a list, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on Ahmad's answer, there are a number of data structures that are built of elements commonly called "nodes" - each node contains some data and some kind of reference (typically a pointer in C and C++) to one or more other nodes.  For a singly-linked list, the node definition typically looks like

```
struct node {
  data_t data;        // for some arbitrary data_t type
  struct node *next;
};
```

Each node contains the address of the following node.  A graphical representation typically looks like

```
+------+------+        +------+------+      +------+------+
| data | next |------->| data | next |----->| data | next |------|||
+------+------+        +------+------+      +------+------+
```

You can also have doubly linked list, where each node points to both the preceding and following nodes:

```
 struct node {
   data_t data;
   struct node *prev;
   struct node *next;
 };
```

And there are binary trees, where each node points to left and right child nodes:

```
 struct node {
   data_t data;
   struct node *left;
   struct node *right;
 };
```

The use of the term "node" is just a common naming convention.

> **A dynamic array can be extended by doubling the size but there is overhead associated with the operation of copying old data and freeing the memory associated with the old data structure.** What is that supposed to mean?

You can resize a dynamically allocated buffer using the `realloc` library function.  For example, suppose we want to dynamically allocate a buffer to
store the string `"foo"`.  We'd write something like:

```
size_t bufsize = 4;
char *buffer = malloc( bufsize ); 
if ( buffer )
  strcpy( buffer, "foo" );
```

We'll imagine the address returned from `malloc` is `0x1000`:

```
        +---+---+---+---+
0x1000: |'f'|'o'|'o'| 0 |
        +---+---+---+---+
0x1004: | ? | ? | ? | ? |
        +---+---+---+---+
         ... ... ... ...
```

Now, suppose we want to append the string `"bar"` to `"foo"`.  We didn't allocate a large enough buffer to do that, so we need to resize it using the `realloc` library function:

```
char *tmp = realloc( buffer, bufsize * 2 ); // double the buffer size
if ( tmp )
{
  buffer = tmp;
  bufsize *= 2;
  strcat( buffer, "bar" );
}
else
{
  // could not extend buffer, handle as appropriate
}
```

Now, if possible, `realloc` will just grab the space following the current buffer, so the result of that code would be:

```
        +---+---+---+---+
0x1000: |'f'|'o'|'o'|'b'|
        +---+---+---+---+
0x1004: |'a'|'r'| 0 | ? |
        +---+---+---+---+
         ... ... ... ...
```

However, if the memory at `0x1004` had already been allocated for something else, then we can't do that.  `realloc` will have to allocate a *new* buffer at a different address and copy the contents of the current buffer into it, then deallocate the original buffer.  We'll imagine that the first region of free space large enough starts at `0x100c`:

```
        +---+---+---+---+
0x1000: |'f'|'o'|'o'| 0 |
        +---+---+---+---+
0x1004: | ? | ? | ? | ? |
        +---+---+---+---+
         ... ... ... ...
        +---+---+---+---+
0x100c: | ? | ? | ? | ? |
        +---+---+---+---+
0x1010: | ? | ? | ? | ? |
        +---+---+---+---+
```

So `realloc` must first allocate the 8 bytes starting at `0x100c`, then it must copy the contents of the current buffer to that new space:

```
        +---+---+---+---+
0x1000: |'f'|'o'|'o'| 0 |
        +---+---+---+---+
0x1004: | ? | ? | ? | ? |
        +---+---+---+---+
         ... ... ... ...
        +---+---+---+---+
0x100c: |'f'|'o'|'o'| 0 |
        +---+---+---+---+
0x1010: | ? | ? | ? | ? |
        +---+---+---+---+
```

and then finally release the space at `0x1000`.  We append `"bar"` to this *new* buffer, giving us:

```
        +---+---+---+---+
0x1000: |'f'|'o'|'o'| 0 | // free'd memory is not overwritten
        +---+---+---+---+
0x1004: | ? | ? | ? | ? |
        +---+---+---+---+
         ... ... ... ...
        +---+---+---+---+
0x100c: |'f'|'o'|'o'|'b'|
        +---+---+---+---+
0x1010: |'a'|'r'| 0 | ? |
        +---+---+---+---+
```

If `realloc` cannot find a large enough region to satisfy the request, it will return `NULL` and leave the current buffer in place.  This is why we assign the return value of `realloc` to a different pointer variable - if we assigned that `NULL` back to `buffer`, then we'd lose our access to the original buffer.

Answer (score 2):

A 'node' is not a C keyword.

The meaning of this:

> A dynamic array can be extended by doubling the size but there is overhead associated with the operation of copying old data and freeing the memory associated with the old data structure

Dynamic allocation means that memory is allocated on the *heap*. The size of the memory space allocated does *not* have to be a compile time constant as in static memory allocation, and thus can be modified by reallocating more memory later on in the program's execution.

Overhead means the *additional cost* of doing an operation in comparison to some other way of doing the same operation. In this case increasing a dynamic array's size is an overhead in comparison with directly allocating the total required space.