# How to count the number of words in a node?

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, cs50

I'm working on cs50 pset5 speller, and I'm on the size function, where you have to count the number of words in the dictionary. I'm trying to count how many things there are in each part of a node (see [What is a node in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63593882/what-is-a-node-in-c)), then add them together to make the total. But I don't know how to do that. Here's my code so far:

```c
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dictionary.h"




// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    for(int i = 65; i < N - 1 + 65; i++)
    {
        char c = i;
       if(word[0] == c)
       {
           return i;
       }

    }
    return 0;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
     if(dictionary == NULL)
     {
         return false;

     }
     FILE* word2 = NULL;
     char* wordread = NULL;
     fopen("r", dictionary);

     while(wordread)
     {

     fscanf(word2, "%s",wordread );
     node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
     strcpy(n->word, wordread);
     n->next = NULL;
     const char *word = wordread;
     
    unsigned int hash(const char *word);
 

     }

    return false;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
   int count = 0;
    // TODO
     for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < strlen(table[i]); j++)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    
    // TODO
   return 1;
    
    return count;
}
```

Focus on the size function. I only added the other code so you can understand some of the variables. I tried googling it, but this problem is very specific and I can't find anything. It's also a problem that I have to keep the function definitions as they are, for example I can't change the size function from this:

```c
unsigned int size(void)
```

to this:

```c
unsigned int size(const char *dictionary)
```

If you have any ideas on how I can fix my code, please tell me even if the bug is in a different function.
Thanks.

Comment: If you do only `count++` in a static for loop like that, then the result is quite predictable. I guess you have a problem there.

Comment: Hint: size only has to report the number of words in the dictionary. Since `load` processes every word in the dictionary, count them there.

Comment: I would probably add a counter of real words into the node structure. Then counting the total number of words would be as simple as summing up the counters in a single loop. You might create a structure of higher level for the dictionary itself and keep track of the total number of words in it. So there are many different solutions to the problem, and I think your question should be more focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must send your `const char *dictionary` to size

Then i expect your diconnary is a char[26] for each letter in the alphabet, verify first that he is perfectly allocated ;)

I also expect that your have an 2D array for each letters.

```
for(int i = 0; dictionary[i]; i++) // mean : while dictionnary isn't NULL
{
    for(int j = 0; j < dictionary[i][j]); j++) // mean : while every word of the letter given by the index i are readed
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```